# Unable to update dependencies with ant

Tags: java, ant

I'm really a beginner with ant, anyway I'm working with a java project built with ant.

There're, simplifying, two projects imported in Eclipse:

- The `project1` contains the `class1` with the `methods1`, `methods2` and `methods3`.
- In `project2` there's a `class2` that call the `class1.method3()`.

The `ivy.xml` on `project2` contains:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="my.package"
                name="project1"
                rev="latest.${project.version.status}"
                conf="default"> 
       <exclude module="servlet-api"/>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The issue is:

> The method method3() is undefined for the type class1
>   (line 53 class2.java)

I've tried several combinations, my "favourite" is:

1. With terminal in `project1` folder:

   - `ant clean-lib lib`
   - `ant publish-local`
2. And in `project2` folder:

   - `ant clean-lib lib`
3. Refresh, clean and build all projects in Eclipse

But it doesn't works, so... how can I update the `project1.jar` referred by `project2`? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: how does project2 refer to project1? Are the two projects to be placed in the same lib directory? If so, does publish replace `project1.jar` that `project2.jar` refers to with the updated one?

Comment: @Ishnark That's a great question. I've added the `ivy.xml` part in question, thanks

Comment: does it work with `latest.integration`

Comment: Yes, it solved my compile error. Please add an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtleties of `latest.[version]` are lost on me, but if you're always going to be picking the newest, then you might as well do `latest.integration`.

(Also according to [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html), it looks like what you were doing is syntactically correct, so maybe `project.version.status` wasn't a proper value)